# Puppeteer form submission; Selecting inputs by name and not id

Tags: javascript, forms, post, puppeteer

I'm trying to learn some javascript by creating a web scraper for majestic.com  , here's their api page, a little down below is the form that I need.

https://developer-support.majestic.com/

Here's my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://developer-support.majestic.com/');
  await page.click('#add-item-button')
  await page.click('#add-item-button')

  await page.type('#try-it-out-input' , 'my api key 987654321')
  await page.select('select[name=item0]', '1234');
  console.log('end');
```

})();

Before submitting anything, program first has to click teh "Add more items" button twice, since I will need to send 3 urls, so I will have 3 input fields in total (this part works). I then grab one of the forms by id (the one that requers API key) and fill it, this works fine too.

My problems start when I try to fill the 3 forms with urls. They don't have id, but they do have names, like item0, item1 and item3, but I couldn't figure out a way to select them. I was hoping someone could point out where the mistake is. Thanks!

Comment: Your final `select` call looks correct to me for selecting via name (maybe needs quotations?). Just make sure you're selecting the correct tag (on my side on the page you linked I don't see any selects with name `item0`, but I do see `<input>`s with the name `item0`.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, the same mistake was pointe out by lejlun, but nopw i get an error :)

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Element is not a <select> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no select tag with `name="item0"` only an input tag, your script works when you use this selector.

```js
await page.select('input[name="item0"]', '1234');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it, but it returns an error, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Element is not a <select> element.

Comment: If you want to type `1234` in the input box, you should use this instead, `await page.type('input[name="item0"]', '1234')` @freemanfl

Comment: 1234 is an example, I will fill the form with url of a website, but I understand what you mean.I tried it and for some reason it fills the worn form! "try it out" instead of num0

https://imgur.com/a/R1tSq6F

Do you think i am selecting the form wrong? Maybe it is some timing issue with how the page loads?

Comment: I've created an SO chat room, join [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235937/room-for-lejlun-and-freemanfl). @freemanfl